# How to play a mix playlist containing youtube, vimeo and flv videos stored on a server?

Tags: video, youtube, flv, vimeo, playlist

i am working on a video streaming website. the user can either upload videos or can add url from youtube and vimeo to add videos. User can also create playlist. I am using flow player playlist plugin for videos stored on server and that is working fine. BUT, when someone adds youtube or vimeo videos into that playlist, flow player is not able to play them. Flow player offers plugins for youtube and vimeo but i can't afford it...

Is there any player that i can use to play this playlist containing youtube, vimeo and flv videos?

any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

What you might need to do is to encode the video into a format that Flow player can play. Use ffmpeg to convert the videos. You can use something like youtube-dl to download the video files from youtube and vimeo.